# Use Xpath with PHP to retrieve the first <y> element that does not have a z attribute set

Tags: php, xpath, xpath-1.0

I'd like to use Xpath with PHP to retrieve the first `<y>` element that does *not* have a z attribute set. How can I do this?

```
Sample XML:
<parent>
    <y z=‘somevalue1’>…</y>
    <y z=‘somevalue2’>…</y>
    <y z=‘somevalue3’>…</y>
    <y>CHOOSE THIS</y>
    <y></y>
</parent>
```

By extension, how can I retrieve the first X `<y>` elements that does not have a z attribute set?

Comment: Minor nit-pick suggestion:  fix the single quotes from `‘somevalue1’` to syntactically correct double-quotes `"somevalue1"` so nobody is distracted by that.

Answer (score 0):

To get the first `y` element without a `z` attribute you can use this expression:

```
//y[not(@z)][1]
```

To retrieve, for example, the first three `<y>` elements that do not have a `z` attribute you can use the `position()` function:

```
//y[not(@z)][position() >= 1 and 3 >= position()]
```